How to make winstonjs format.cli to show the timestamp?
I am using winstonjs logger with typescript
"winston": "^3.13.0"

I do create the logger like this
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';

const IS_CLI_MODE = process.env.IS_CLI_MODE === 'true';

export const logger = createLogger({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug',
    format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        }),
        format.errors({ stack: true }),
        format.splat(),
        ...(IS_CLI_MODE ? [format.cli()] : [format.json()]),
    ),
    transports: [new transports.Console(), new transports.File({ filename: 'app.log' })],
});


If IS_CLI_MODE is false, the timestamp is working fine inside the format.json
If I am using format.cli() the timestamp is not shown.
Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance
